# Detect modal dialogs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample website for modal example : "http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/#modal", goal is to identify whether the website opened modal window or not. Is there any way using java-script to achieve the goal ?

Note: I want to detect modal window and not alert/pop-up windows, without prior knowledge of modal window "id" or any attributes.

Comment: And why you want it so?

Comment: Did you already write some code? I mean do you have a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A super simple way (in your case) could be just to check:

```
if ($('.remodal-is-opened') !== undefined) {
  //open!
}
```

However a better way as per the api could be to call `inst.getState();` instead:

```
var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();

/**
 * Opens the modal window
 */
inst.open();


/**
 * Returns a current state of the modal
 * @returns {'closed'|'closing'|'opened'|'opening'}
 */
inst.getState();
```

Ref: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#methods

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this code

```
if($('.remodal-is-opened')){
console.log("modal open")
}else console.log("modal closed");
```